# Re-organize json-format with python

Tags: python, json

I want the output to be easily readable by all people in Json format. Right now the output is a big long string of data. The goal is to be able to see the data at a glance. So in the original format of JSON.

**Wanted output (example)**

```
[
 {
  "Employee ID": 1,
  "Name": "Abhishek",
  "Designation": "Software Engineer"
 },
 {
  "Employee ID": 2,
  "Name": "Garima",
  "Designation": "Email Marketing Specialist"
 }
]
[
   {
      "Employee ID": 1,
      "Name": "Abhishek",
      "Designation": "Software Engineer"
   },
   {
      "Employee ID": 2,
      "Name": "Garima",
      "Designation": "Email Marketing Specialist"
   }
]
```

**Python main code:**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Start-up")
    api = APIClient(AMV_TOKEN, AMV_IP2)
    print(api.batch.get())
    print("Done")
```

**Output:**

```
Start-up
{'count': 8, 'next': None, 'previous': None, 'results': [{'url': 'http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/bmw_problem/', 'created': '2021-05-11T16:56:04.944370+02:00', 'modified': '2021-05-11T16:56:04.944384+02:00', 'id': 'bmw_problem', 'title': 'bmw_problem', 'archived': False, 'view': None, 'query': 'tray=bmw_problem', 'summary': 
{'prints': 11, 'assigned': 11, 'rejected': 0, 'conflicted': 0, 'needs_processing': False, 'processing_ratio': 1.0, 'processing_status': 'READY', 'currently_scanning': None}, 'has_bin_assignments': True, 'active_scan_session': '677d2328-6276-4206-9a69-2f6b10fd67ea', 'auto_delete': False}, {'url': 'http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/demo_set_3/', 'created': '2021-03-22T12:37:51.240377+01:00', 'modified': '2021-04-12T12:27:07.124319+02:00', 'id': 'demo_set_3', 'title': 'demo_set_3', 'archived': False, 'view': 'by_tray', 'query': 'tray=demo_set_3', 'summary': {'prints': 318, 'assigned': 0, 'rejected': 0, 'conflicted': 0, 'needs_processing': False, 'processing_ratio': 1.0, 'processing_status': 'READY', 'currently_scanning': False}, 'has_bin_assignments': False, 'active_scan_session': None, 'auto_delete': False}, {'url': 'http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/demo_all/', 'created': '2021-03-04T11:52:05.236265+01:00', 'modified': '2021-05-12T12:05:58.546004+02:00', 'id': 'demo_all', 'title': 'All demo parts', 'archived': False, 'view': 'by_tray', 'query': 'tray__istartswith=demo_set_', 'summary': {'prints': 1252, 'assigned': 218, 'rejected': 0, 'conflicted': 0, 'needs_processing': False, 'processing_ratio': 1.0, 'processing_status': 'READY', 'currently_scanning': None}, 'has_bin_assignments': True, 'active_scan_session': '50d5119e-57ef-4577-b0b4-090839f27f0d', 'auto_delete': False}, {'url': 'http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/priority/', 'created': '2021-03-04T11:50:06.446579+01:00', 'modified': '2021-03-22T13:09:14.910389+01:00', 'id': 'priority', 'title': 'Priority Prints', 'archived': False, 'view': None, 'query': 
'flags__contains=PRIORITY', 'summary': {'prints': 434, 'assigned': 0, 'rejected': 0, 'conflicted': 0, 'needs_processing': False, 'processing_ratio': 1.0, 'processing_status': 'READY', 'currently_scanning': None}, 'has_bin_assignments': True, 'active_scan_session': '15403217-a468-498e-b150-b900a16cd5cc', 'auto_delete': False}, {'url': 'http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/MJF/', 'created': '2021-03-04T11:50:06.446557+01:00', 'modified': '2021-05-12T12:05:58.546004+02:00', 'id': 'MJF', 'title': 'MJF Prints', 'archived': False, 'view': 'by_tech', 'query': 'technology=MJF', 'summary': {'prints': 138, 'assigned': 0, 'rejected': 0, 'conflicted': 0, 'needs_processing': False, 'processing_ratio': 1.0, 'processing_status': 'READY', 'currently_scanning': None}, 'has_bin_assignments': False, 'active_scan_session': '81f0ffdd-1e82-4e42-b8fb-89a661b03924', 'auto_delete': False}, {'url': 'http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/SLS/', 'created': '2021-03-04T11:50:06.446534+01:00', 'modified': '2021-05-12T12:05:58.546004+02:00', 'id': 'SLS', 'title': 'SLS Prints', 'archived': False, 'view': 'by_tech', 'query': 'technology=SLS', 'summary': {'prints': 1114, 'assigned': 1, 'rejected': 0, 'conflicted': 0, 'needs_processing': False, 'processing_ratio': 1.0, 'processing_status': 'READY', 'currently_scanning': None}, 'has_bin_assignments': True, 'active_scan_session': '99b3a0a3-05f6-4225-bbe6-9814a31dca80', 'auto_delete': False}, {'url': 'http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/demo_set_2/', 'created': '2021-03-04T11:50:06.446508+01:00', 'modified': '2021-05-12T12:05:58.546004+02:00', 'id': 'demo_set_2', 'title': 'demo_set_2', 'archived': False, 'view': 'by_tray', 'query': 'tray=demo_set_2', 'summary': {'prints': 323, 'assigned': 22, 'rejected': 0, 'conflicted': 0, 'needs_processing': False, 'processing_ratio': 1.0, 'processing_status': 'READY', 'currently_scanning': True}, 'has_bin_assignments': True, 'active_scan_session': '82e8e71a-0c1f-41c5-b021-bd399eb2d6b3', 'auto_delete': False}, {'url': 'http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/demo_set_1/', 'created': '2021-03-04T11:50:06.446461+01:00', 'modified': '2021-05-12T12:05:58.546004+02:00', 'id': 'demo_set_1', 'title': 'demo_set_1', 'archived': False, 'view': 'by_tray', 'query': 'tray=demo_set_1', 'summary': {'prints': 611, 'assigned': 
0, 'rejected': 0, 'conflicted': 0, 'needs_processing': False, 'processing_ratio': 1.0, 'processing_status': 'READY', 'currently_scanning': None}, 'has_bin_assignments': False, 'active_scan_session': 'becc3aba-bba4-4061-8a19-65abec2acbcd', 'auto_delete': False}], 'num_pages': 1, 'processing': False}
Done
```

Comment: the example does not match the data... please add futher explaination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use the standard [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library.  In your case this would make it easier to read:

```
import json

my_dict = {'count': 8, 'next': None, 'previous': None, 'results': [{'url': 'http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/bmw_problem/', 'created': '2021-05-11T16:56:04.944370+02:00', 'modified': '2021-05-11T16:56:04.944384+02:00', 'id': 'bmw_problem', 'title': 'bmw_problem', 'archived': False, 'view': None, 'query': 'tray=bmw_problem', 'summary':
{'prints': 11, 'assigned': 11, 'rejected': 0, 'conflicted': 0, 'needs_processing': False, 'processing_ratio': 1.0, 'processing_status': 'READY', 'currently_scanning': None}, 'has_bin_assignments': True, 'active_scan_session': '677d2328-6276-4206-9a69-2f6b10fd67ea', 'auto_delete': False}, {'url': 'http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/demo_set_3/', 'created': '2021-03-22T12:37:51.240377+01:00', 'modified': '2021-04-12T12:27:07.124319+02:00', 'id': 'demo_set_3', 'title': 'demo_set_3', 'archived': False, 'view': 'by_tray', 'query': 'tray=demo_set_3', 'summary': {'prints': 318, 'assigned': 0, 'rejected': 0, 'conflicted': 0, 'needs_processing': False, 'processing_ratio': 1.0, 'processing_status': 'READY', 'currently_scanning': False}, 'has_bin_assignments': False, 'active_scan_session': None, 'auto_delete': False}, {'url': 'http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/demo_all/', 'created': '2021-03-04T11:52:05.236265+01:00', 'modified': '2021-05-12T12:05:58.546004+02:00', 'id': 'demo_all', 'title': 'All demo parts', 'archived': False, 'view': 'by_tray', 'query': 'tray__istartswith=demo_set_', 'summary': {'prints': 1252, 'assigned': 218, 'rejected': 0, 'conflicted': 0, 'needs_processing': False, 'processing_ratio': 1.0, 'processing_status': 'READY', 'currently_scanning': None}, 'has_bin_assignments': True, 'active_scan_session': '50d5119e-57ef-4577-b0b4-090839f27f0d', 'auto_delete': False}, {'url': 'http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/priority/', 'created': '2021-03-04T11:50:06.446579+01:00', 'modified': '2021-03-22T13:09:14.910389+01:00', 'id': 'priority', 'title': 'Priority Prints', 'archived': False, 'view': None, 'query':
'flags__contains=PRIORITY', 'summary': {'prints': 434, 'assigned': 0, 'rejected': 0, 'conflicted': 0, 'needs_processing': False, 'processing_ratio': 1.0, 'processing_status': 'READY', 'currently_scanning': None}, 'has_bin_assignments': True, 'active_scan_session': '15403217-a468-498e-b150-b900a16cd5cc', 'auto_delete': False}, {'url': 'http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/MJF/', 'created': '2021-03-04T11:50:06.446557+01:00', 'modified': '2021-05-12T12:05:58.546004+02:00', 'id': 'MJF', 'title': 'MJF Prints', 'archived': False, 'view': 'by_tech', 'query': 'technology=MJF', 'summary': {'prints': 138, 'assigned': 0, 'rejected': 0, 'conflicted': 0, 'needs_processing': False, 'processing_ratio': 1.0, 'processing_status': 'READY', 'currently_scanning': None}, 'has_bin_assignments': False, 'active_scan_session': '81f0ffdd-1e82-4e42-b8fb-89a661b03924', 'auto_delete': False}, {'url': 'http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/SLS/', 'created': '2021-03-04T11:50:06.446534+01:00', 'modified': '2021-05-12T12:05:58.546004+02:00', 'id': 'SLS', 'title': 'SLS Prints', 'archived': False, 'view': 'by_tech', 'query': 'technology=SLS', 'summary': {'prints': 1114, 'assigned': 1, 'rejected': 0, 'conflicted': 0, 'needs_processing': False, 'processing_ratio': 1.0, 'processing_status': 'READY', 'currently_scanning': None}, 'has_bin_assignments': True, 'active_scan_session': '99b3a0a3-05f6-4225-bbe6-9814a31dca80', 'auto_delete': False}, {'url': 'http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/demo_set_2/', 'created': '2021-03-04T11:50:06.446508+01:00', 'modified': '2021-05-12T12:05:58.546004+02:00', 'id': 'demo_set_2', 'title': 'demo_set_2', 'archived': False, 'view': 'by_tray', 'query': 'tray=demo_set_2', 'summary': {'prints': 323, 'assigned': 22, 'rejected': 0, 'conflicted': 0, 'needs_processing': False, 'processing_ratio': 1.0, 'processing_status': 'READY', 'currently_scanning': True}, 'has_bin_assignments': True, 'active_scan_session': '82e8e71a-0c1f-41c5-b021-bd399eb2d6b3', 'auto_delete': False}, {'url': 'http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/demo_set_1/', 'created': '2021-03-04T11:50:06.446461+01:00', 'modified': '2021-05-12T12:05:58.546004+02:00', 'id': 'demo_set_1', 'title': 'demo_set_1', 'archived': False, 'view': 'by_tray', 'query': 'tray=demo_set_1', 'summary': {'prints': 611, 'assigned':
0, 'rejected': 0, 'conflicted': 0, 'needs_processing': False, 'processing_ratio': 1.0, 'processing_status': 'READY', 'currently_scanning': None}, 'has_bin_assignments': False, 'active_scan_session': 'becc3aba-bba4-4061-8a19-65abec2acbcd', 'auto_delete': False}], 'num_pages': 1, 'processing': False}

print(json.dumps(my_dict, indent=4, sort_keys=True)) # or use my_dict['results'] if you just want the results

>>
{
    "count": 8,
    "next": null,
    "num_pages": 1,
    "previous": null,
    "processing": false,
    "results": [
        {
            "active_scan_session": "677d2328-6276-4206-9a69-2f6b10fd67ea",
            "archived": false,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "created": "2021-05-11T16:56:04.944370+02:00",
            "has_bin_assignments": true,
            "id": "bmw_problem",
            "modified": "2021-05-11T16:56:04.944384+02:00",
            "query": "tray=bmw_problem",
            "summary": {
                "assigned": 11,
                "conflicted": 0,
                "currently_scanning": null,
                "needs_processing": false,
                "prints": 11,
                "processing_ratio": 1.0,
                "processing_status": "READY",
                "rejected": 0
            },
            "title": "bmw_problem",
            "url": "http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/bmw_problem/",
            "view": null
        },
        {
            "active_scan_session": null,
            "archived": false,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "created": "2021-03-22T12:37:51.240377+01:00",
            "has_bin_assignments": false,
            "id": "demo_set_3",
            "modified": "2021-04-12T12:27:07.124319+02:00",
            "query": "tray=demo_set_3",
            "summary": {
                "assigned": 0,
                "conflicted": 0,
                "currently_scanning": false,
                "needs_processing": false,
                "prints": 318,
                "processing_ratio": 1.0,
                "processing_status": "READY",
                "rejected": 0
            },
            "title": "demo_set_3",
            "url": "http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/demo_set_3/",
            "view": "by_tray"
        },
        {
            "active_scan_session": "50d5119e-57ef-4577-b0b4-090839f27f0d",
            "archived": false,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "created": "2021-03-04T11:52:05.236265+01:00",
            "has_bin_assignments": true,
            "id": "demo_all",
            "modified": "2021-05-12T12:05:58.546004+02:00",
            "query": "tray__istartswith=demo_set_",
            "summary": {
                "assigned": 218,
                "conflicted": 0,
                "currently_scanning": null,
                "needs_processing": false,
                "prints": 1252,
                "processing_ratio": 1.0,
                "processing_status": "READY",
                "rejected": 0
            },
            "title": "All demo parts",
            "url": "http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/demo_all/",
            "view": "by_tray"
        },
        {
            "active_scan_session": "15403217-a468-498e-b150-b900a16cd5cc",
            "archived": false,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "created": "2021-03-04T11:50:06.446579+01:00",
            "has_bin_assignments": true,
            "id": "priority",
            "modified": "2021-03-22T13:09:14.910389+01:00",
            "query": "flags__contains=PRIORITY",
            "summary": {
                "assigned": 0,
                "conflicted": 0,
                "currently_scanning": null,
                "needs_processing": false,
                "prints": 434,
                "processing_ratio": 1.0,
                "processing_status": "READY",
                "rejected": 0
            },
            "title": "Priority Prints",
            "url": "http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/priority/",
            "view": null
        },
        {
            "active_scan_session": "81f0ffdd-1e82-4e42-b8fb-89a661b03924",
            "archived": false,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "created": "2021-03-04T11:50:06.446557+01:00",
            "has_bin_assignments": false,
            "id": "MJF",
            "modified": "2021-05-12T12:05:58.546004+02:00",
            "query": "technology=MJF",
            "summary": {
                "assigned": 0,
                "conflicted": 0,
                "currently_scanning": null,
                "needs_processing": false,
                "prints": 138,
                "processing_ratio": 1.0,
                "processing_status": "READY",
                "rejected": 0
            },
            "title": "MJF Prints",
            "url": "http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/MJF/",
            "view": "by_tech"
        },
        {
            "active_scan_session": "99b3a0a3-05f6-4225-bbe6-9814a31dca80",
            "archived": false,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "created": "2021-03-04T11:50:06.446534+01:00",
            "has_bin_assignments": true,
            "id": "SLS",
            "modified": "2021-05-12T12:05:58.546004+02:00",
            "query": "technology=SLS",
            "summary": {
                "assigned": 1,
                "conflicted": 0,
                "currently_scanning": null,
                "needs_processing": false,
                "prints": 1114,
                "processing_ratio": 1.0,
                "processing_status": "READY",
                "rejected": 0
            },
            "title": "SLS Prints",
            "url": "http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/SLS/",
            "view": "by_tech"
        },
        {
            "active_scan_session": "82e8e71a-0c1f-41c5-b021-bd399eb2d6b3",
            "archived": false,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "created": "2021-03-04T11:50:06.446508+01:00",
            "has_bin_assignments": true,
            "id": "demo_set_2",
            "modified": "2021-05-12T12:05:58.546004+02:00",
            "query": "tray=demo_set_2",
            "summary": {
                "assigned": 22,
                "conflicted": 0,
                "currently_scanning": true,
                "needs_processing": false,
                "prints": 323,
                "processing_ratio": 1.0,
                "processing_status": "READY",
                "rejected": 0
            },
            "title": "demo_set_2",
            "url": "http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/demo_set_2/",
            "view": "by_tray"
        },
        {
            "active_scan_session": "becc3aba-bba4-4061-8a19-65abec2acbcd",
            "archived": false,
            "auto_delete": false,
            "created": "2021-03-04T11:50:06.446461+01:00",
            "has_bin_assignments": false,
            "id": "demo_set_1",
            "modified": "2021-05-12T12:05:58.546004+02:00",
            "query": "tray=demo_set_1",
            "summary": {
                "assigned": 0,
                "conflicted": 0,
                "currently_scanning": null,
                "needs_processing": false,
                "prints": 611,
                "processing_ratio": 1.0,
                "processing_status": "READY",
                "rejected": 0
            },
            "title": "demo_set_1",
            "url": "http://192.168.0.18/api/batch/demo_set_1/",
            "view": "by_tray"
        }
    ]
}
```